# What is the Eclipse equivalent of the NetBeans "Run As Main"?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

What is the Eclipse equivalent of the NetBeans "Run As Main"?

I have a Java "main" class that contains the start code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Then I have another class `foo` that has a method `bar`.

When I am displaying (editing) the main class, and click the run icon, it runs normally.  But when I am editing the foo class, and click the run icon, it says:

> The selection did not contain any resources that may run on a server

NetBeans always knows to run the main class. Eclipse doesn't. Is there any way to teach Eclipse to play nicely?

Comment: does class `foo` contain a `main` method?

Comment: No main class in foo.  The main class is in "main".  Foo is called from main.  I am looking to teach Eclipse to remember the entry point of the program.

Comment: You can't execute a class that has no `main` method

Comment: Lino -  I know that.  That is why I have a main class. I am looking to teach Eclipse to remember the entry point of the program.  Seems like a reasonable request.

Comment: No, Even if you update the foo class which does not have the run method.The run icon will run the main class with main method. Eclipse is pretty smart than you think. First time just run your class with main method as--> Java application and It will remember you main class.

Comment: Null Pointer - If it was that easy, then I wouldn't have submitted the question and spent all this time on it.  I am getting highly frustrated with Eclipse.  Such a simple thing is so hard.  I guess that I will need to perform the "work-around" and just switch back to the main class before running.  Seems such a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Preferences and in "`Run/Debug`" > "`Launching`" choose "`Always launch the previously launched Application`" (below "`Launch Operation`").

Then, right-click on your `Main` class and choose "`Run-As`" > "`Java Application`". Now when you edit your other classes and you click the run-button, `Main` will be launched again.

Comment: Thank you - it works!  This should be the default setting!

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Run -> Run Configurations` select your `project` and select `Main` class and click on `Apply` button and `Run` button

This will always run from your `selected` `main` class

Comment: Thank you too.  I marked the answer from Till Brychcy as the solution, but your solution works also.